# Header y Tail Python

Tags: python

He cargado un archivo `.csv` en Python y me gustaría observar los 5 primeros datos tanto de arriba como de abajo de la lista, sin embargo cuando escribo:

```
datos.head()
datos.tail()
```

solo me aparecen las del final, ¿sabéis si hay alguna manera de que aparezcan ambas?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que estás en un Jupyter notebook.

### Qué ocurre

El resultado que se muestra al ejecutar una celda es sólo el de la última expresión evaluada (salvo que la celda contenga prints). Por tanto, si en una celda pones:

```
datos.head()
datos.tail()
```

La primera expresión se evalúa, pero `datos.head()` no significa "mostrar las primeras líneas", sino "obtener un dataframe con las primeras líneas". El resultado de esa operación sería un nuevo dataframe, pero al no asignarse a ninguna variable, el resultado se pierde.

En la segunda línea ocurre algo análogo, pero por ser la última línea de la celda, su resultado se muestra.

Es algo similar a lo que ocurriría si escribieras en una celda:

```
2 * 3
5 * 3
```

pues verías sólo 15.

### Soluciones

Si quieres que algo sea visible en la salida, debes usar funciones que vuelquen algo a la salida. Por ejemplo `print()`:

```
print(datos.head())
print(datos.tail())
```

El problema es que `print()` fuerza a que el resultado sea "tipo texto", que es más feo que lo que el notebook te muestra por defecto (que es una tabla HTML mucho mejor formateada).

Para forzar a que te vuelque la tabla como HTML puedes usar la función  `display()`:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(datos.head())
display(datos.tail())
```

Otra solución por supuesto es ejecutar `datos.head()` en una celda y `datos.tail()` en otra.

Comment: Creo que optaré por dividir en dos celdas el resultado para mejor compresión. Muchas gracias!!